# Excel VBA: "For" and "If" statement on a single line?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

Is it somehow possible in VBA to put a `For` and `If` statement in a single line?
The closest what I could get is this:

```
For i = 0 To n: If a = i Then a = b
Next i
```

If I write:

```
For i = 0 To n: If a = i Then a = b: Next i
```

I get the "**Next without For**" error.

Comment: Why do you need it in a single line?

Comment: Just for reading. For short and simple code parts it's often easier to read and "grasp" the code on one line rather than putting everything on its own line.

Comment: Not an answer, but you'll find the same behavior with *all* of VBA's looping structures (`For...Next`, `Do...Loop`, `While...Wend`, `For Each...Next`).  My hunch is that it has to do with some combination of how the compiler has to deal with line numbers and debugging breakpoints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with `IIf`, rather than `If`.

This code won't throw the error:

```
For i = 0 To n: IIf a = i, a = b, False: Next i
```

Comment: The only disadvantage is that you cannot omit the True or False clause. Is it possible to have multiple statements inside the True or False part?

Comment: a = b within the IIf clause is a comparison that will yield true or false, and is not an assigment statement giving the value of b to a.

Answer (score 4):

Use `select case` instead of if...

`For i = 0 To n: select case a = i: case true: a = b: end select: Next i`