# What reason(s) NOT to place multiple lines of VBA code on a single line separated by colons?

Tags: excel, vba, line-separator

We are building a local library of VBA functions at our business, and the length of code in several modules has become a bit lengthy, and there is no (known) method collapse sections of code. We have started to consolidate the simpler functions (tested, known-good, simple functions) into colon-delimited line(s), for the ability to easily scroll through code. Question is, what are the reasons NOT to do so? The only thing we've found is that breakpoints/debugging may at worst be a hurdle, but the code is solid, and we could split the lines out should there ever be a need for a deep dive. Anybody with experience, ideas, suggestions on this?  TIA

Obv:
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725118/excel-vba-colon)

and
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477377/excel-vba-for-and-if-statement-on-a-single-line)

Comment: "The only thing we've found is that breakpoints/debugging may at worst be a hurdle" well, seems you have answered your question. Also, long lines are hard to read and hard to reason about. So .... probably in a few years someone will come along and say "what's the deal with all these long lines here?" and start cursing the idiot who wrote that code. That future person might even be you...

Comment: Thanks, yes we fully anticipate(d) the future repercussion(s).  The code can be split, if needed. We were questioning if there is any compiler/efficiency hit involved with this method, versus line-by-line coding. And yes, I'm quite sure that I will be that person... Thanks, again for your help!

Comment: You are aware of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/line-too-long

Comment: Aware now, DNK, thanks!  FWIW, doubt that lines will exceed the max, but useful info for sure.

Comment: *... the length of code in several modules has become a bit lengthy*  Why is that a problem? Especially if it improves readability and future debugging or updating efforts.

Comment: https://nolongerset.com/beautiful-blocks-of-boilerplate/#joining-lines-of-code-with-the-colon-character  
https://nolongerset.com/better-global-constants/#the-constcountyid-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question is, what are the reasons NOT to do so?**

`If` statements.

As pointed out in your 2nd example - but not noted in your question. There are workarounds, but almost any code will have a few `If` statements in it.

Consider the following code:

```
For i = 0 To n
    If a = i Then a = b
Next i
```

The `If` statement is effectively:

```
If a = i Then [a = b]
```

This is because anything after the `Then` (until an optional `Else` or `End If`) is performed when a = i.

So if you attempt to consolidate this with colons, like so:

```
For i = 0 To n : If a = i Then a = b : Next i
```

.. then it compiles to:

```
For i = 0 To n : If a = i Then [a = b : Next i]
```

So the Next i is only performed where a = i.

As the link you provided does note, there are alternatives. But most people like using `If`.

Comment: That is an example of what we were questioning.  Moving forward, we will not be colon-izing FOR/NEXT loops. Anybody with other potential issues, please advise. Thank you very much!

Comment: I would check any instances of `If` statements. That is where the behaviour alters.

Comment: Thanks - we're not planning to go crazy on the line-count minimization thing, but believe it will help, as mentioned, in areas of known-good code. If you think of any other such concerns, I will be monitoring.  -JD